# Code igniter - Echo a variable from my array on my view

Tags: php, sql, arrays, codeigniter, variables

Im a designer that i´m taking my first steps on the programing área, mostly on PHP / MySQL. Past week i need to add a blog section on a page made with code igniter.

I make the secction that show all post in order (title and published date). I made a view that takes the id to show the content. But i can`t echo any of the variables.

When i use var_dump or print and it takes all the variables without any problem.

Did i miss somehting? :(

Thank you.

Model:

```
class blog extends CI_Model { 

    public function get($id){
         $this->db->select('id, title, description, icon, uri, published_at');
         $this->db->from('blogs');
         $this->db->where('id', $id);
         $query = $this->db->get();
         $data  = $query->result();
         return $query->result();
    if(!empty($data)){
    return $this->make_groups($data);
}
}
}
```

Controller:

```
Class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function blog_detail($id) {

        $this->load->model('blog');

        if($data = $this->blog->get($id)) {

            $this->load->model('blog');
            $this->data['blog_menu'] = TRUE;
            $this->data['blog'] = $data;

            $this->data['og'] = array(
                'description' => 'INFO',
                'image' => site_url('assets/images/og/blog.png')
            );

          # layout config

            $this->layout->add_css(site_url('assets/css/blog.css'));
            $this->layout->title_for_layout = "TITLE";
            $this->layout->meta = array(
                array('name' => 'description', 'content' => 'DETAIL'),
                array('name' => 'keywords', 'content' => 'KEYWORDS'),
            );

            $this->layout->render('pages/blog_detail/index', $this->data);

        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
<?php var_dump($this->data);
echo $blog->published_at; ?>
```

Comment: Put capital for `class Blog extends CI_Model`. Is `Layout` library autoloaded?

Comment: Fixed the class issue. The layout its autoloaded.
The array with the data is send to the view, but i can show it. I doing something wrong with my echo. When i make var_dump($this->data); i have array(3) { ["blog_menu"]=> bool(true) ["blog"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#23 (6) { ["id"]=> string(2) "11" ["title"]=> string(8) "Prueba 2" ["description"]=> string(19) "
Prueba 2 - 2   But when i try to echo i dont really know how to do that.

Comment: In var_dump output you can notice that `blog` is array with one element that is an object. You can access it with `$blog[0]->title`. You can avoid zero key if you issue `row()` or `row_array()` method in model instead of `result()` which is usual when you are dealing with exact id methods (i.e. get one, edit, delete etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your model you are not returning the result

Check that the filenames and class names only have the first letter upper case.

Blog_model.php

```
class Blog_model extends CI_Model { 

    public function get($id) {
        $this->db->select('id, title, description, icon, uri, published_at');
        $this->db->from('blogs');
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get();

        return $query->row_array();
    }
}
```

Controller

controllers > Pages.php

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

   public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->model('blog_model');               
   }

    public function blog_detail($id) {

        $blog_data = $this->blog_model->get($id);

        if($blog_data)) {


            $this->data['blog_menu'] = TRUE;

            $this->data['published_at'] = $blog_data['published_at'];

            var_dump($blog_data);

            $this->data['og'] = array(
                'description' => 'INFO',
                'image' => site_url('assets/images/og/blog.png')
            );

          # layout config

            $this->layout->add_css(site_url('assets/css/blog.css'));
            $this->layout->title_for_layout = "TITLE";
            $this->layout->meta = array(
                array('name' => 'description', 'content' => 'DETAIL'),
                array('name' => 'keywords', 'content' => 'KEYWORDS'),
            );

            $this->layout->render('pages/blog_detail/index', $this->data);

        }
    }
}
```

View

```
<?php echo $published_at;?>
```

Comment: I checked the class name (Upper case just the first letter) and the file name, everything is fine now.
Sorry about the model. It has a return if the date is not empty. I will edit my example.

The data is sent to the view but i can´t show it. 

If i put on my view  echo $blog->title; the page tell me "Message: Trying to get property of non-object" so it means that i doing the echo totaly wrong .

Comment: Try the way I have put it on the controller and view